# Compare two arrays and find the index of uncommon elements in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, compare

**Arrays are of type String**. Since It is time consuming to add "", I have written it like Int. Sorry.

I have two arrays say `var array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]` and

```
var array2 = [[1,2,3,4],
              [2,3,4,5],
              [2,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
              [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

I have to compare each array element of `array2` with `array1` and insert '-' where the elements do not match. Like this,

```
var array2 = [[1,2,3,4,-,-,-,-,-],
              [-,2,3,4,5,-,-,-,-],
              [-,2,-,4,5,6,-,-,-],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-],
              [-,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-]]
```

I tried to iterate over each array in array2 and compare it with array1, compare the indices and insert '-' to at index position **i**, but I am getting unexpected results.

**UPDATE**

```
 for item in array2{
var elementsArray = item
for i  in stride(from: 0, to: elementsArray.count, by: 1) {
    if elementsArray[i] != array1[i]
    {
        elementsArray.insert("-", at: i)
    }
    print("elemnt array.....", elementsArray, "\n\n")
}
}
```

I had thought of comparing each array of array2 with array1 by `count`, find the index of uncommon element and then insert '-' at that index position. Is this approach right? Please help me with this.

Comment: Is `array1` supposed to be a one dimensional array or an array of arrays? In the latter case should the i-th subarray of `array1` be compared to the i-th subarray of `array2`?

Comment: About each array in `array2`, can it's length be greater than the length of `array1`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor `array1` is one dimensional only.

Comment: Are the numbers from the second array always present in the first array? Are the numbers always increasing?

Comment: @Adeel no It cannot be greater. Max length of array present in array2 is equal to array1

Comment: @MartinR I didn't really get your question sorry.  But yes, numbers are present. array2 can be of any length.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Hello. Please see the UPDATE in quest. This is what i thought, but I am getting all wrong results

Comment: What I mean is: Can a row in the second array be `[2, 4, 99]` (with 99 not present in the first array)? Can a row in the second array be `[3, 2, 1]` (different order than in the first array)?

Comment: No order does not change. I have sorted the array and no different element can be present.  Elements from array1 are present in array2.

Comment: can the elements in `array2` repeat? I mean can there be a subarray of sort `[1, 2, 2, 3]`?

Comment: can the elements in `array2` repeat? I mean can there be a subarray of sort `[1, 2, 2, 3]`?

Comment: If I change elementsArray.count to array1.count, then I am getting IndexOutOfBounds exception. because I am getting elementsArray of different length so I tried that way.

Comment: @Adeel. No the elements cannot repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a new array where each row of `array2` is replaced by a variant of
`array1`, with elements not originally present in the row replaced by "-":

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let array2 = [[1,2,3,4],
              [2,3,4,5],
              [2,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
              [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]

let filled = array2.map { row in 
    array1.map {
        row.contains($0) ? String($0) : "-"
    }
}

for row in filled { print(row) }
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
["-", "2", "3", "4", "5", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
["-", "2", "-", "4", "5", "6", "-", "-", "-"]
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "-"]
["-", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "-"]
```

For large arrays this can be improved by creating a `Set(row)` for
a faster containment check, or by utilizing that the elements
are in increasing order.

Your approach does not work correctly because `elementsArray` 
is modified while iterating over it.

Comment: Yippie...!! It worked... Thanks a alot. :) Based on array1 and array2 result there is one more array array3 with different data. The problem is I have to set the values of array3 like array2 by matching it each element of the array2. Please help.

Comment: @Bella: I have tried to answer your question. If you have an additional problem, please try to solve it yourself first, with the tools provided in this answer. If necessary, ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry. What if there is no array1 And I have to solve problem only for array2. I am trying by best to solve it, but not getting proper way

Comment: I think to solve that without array1 you need to add an step to find which array is bigger and take as reference in this case your bigger array in array2 will be your array1 @Bella